# foreman start error in sharetribe installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, foreman, sharetribe

## Sharetribe Version:

e5a04ab8fc6628bf33d453482433f4a096b356092

## Environment:

Ubuntu 14 in dev, 16.04 in production

## Server mode:

Development and production also

## Description:

Getting different error in different environment

## Steps To Reproduce:

```
foreman start -f Procfile.static
```

gives  me the following error in development

> Webpack dev build for Rails
>   Server JS bundle missing after waiting for 30 seconds: 'app/assets/webpack/server-bundle.js'
>   exited with code 1

## Additional information

In production i did follow this tutorial https://github.com/asm-products/lancrapp/blob/master/docs/vps-deployment.md

```
ActionView::Template::Error (ERROR in SERVER PRERENDERING
App 6284 stdout: Encountered error: "ReferenceError: ReactOnRails is not defined"
App 6284 stdout: when prerendering OnboardingTopBar with props: {"progress":28.57142857142857,"next_step":"slogan_and_description"}
App 6284 stdout: js_code was:
App 6284 stdout: (function() {
App 6284 stdout:   var railsContext = {"href":"http://x.x.x.x/","location":"/","scheme":"http","host":"x.x.x.x","port":80,"pathname":"/","search":null,"i18nLocale":"en","i18nDefaultLocale":"en","httpAcceptLanguage":"en-US,en;q=0.8","marketplaceId":2,"loggedInUsername":"loveb","marketplace_color1":"#4a90e2","marketplace_color2":"#2ab865","serverSide":true};
App 6284 stdout: 
App 6284 stdout:   var props = {"progress":28.57142857142857,"next_step":"slogan_and_description"};
App 6284 stdout:   return ReactOnRails.serverRenderReactComponent({
App 6284 stdout:     name: 'OnboardingTopBar',
App 6284 stdout:     domNodeId: 'OnboardingTopBar-react-component-0',
App 6284 stdout:     props: props,
App 6284 stdout:     trace: false,
App 6284 stdout:     railsContext: railsContext
App 6284 stdout:   });
App 6284 stdout: })()
```

Comment: Also i tried to precompile in production i get this error   @ build:client /home/deploy/sharetribe/releases/20160823101023/client
> webpack --config webpack.client.config.js

/home/deploy/sharetribe/releases/20160823101023/client/webpack.client.config.js:8
const { replacePercentChar } = require('./webpackConfigUtil');
      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)

Comment: Above error from this file line 8 - https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe/blob/master/client/webpack.client.config.js